# How to solve equation involving normal distribution cdf and confidence level

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I am trying to study/solve a problem that I discussed with some friends, and I would be happy with some inputs.

Assume

$$X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$$

Question is then, what is the smallest value of $\alpha$ that satisfies:

$$P(X \leq 10) = \alpha$$

Such that the following statement is true

$$P(X \leq 15) = 0.80$$

I thought about this problem quite a bit. $\alpha$ must be smaller than $0.80$, since $P(X \leq 10)$ is a more strict statement than $P(X \leq 15)$.

Maybe this can be set up as a proper equation where $P(X \leq 10)$ is written as $P(X \leq 10 + 5)$, but I am not sure if I can apply any rules here to solve for $\alpha$.

For example (I know this is false):
$$P(X \leq 15) = 0.80$$
$$P(X \leq 10) + P(X \leq 5) = 0.80$$
$$P(X \leq 10) = 0.80 - P(X \leq 5)$$
which would then give me $\alpha = 0.80 - P(X \leq 5)$. Again, I know this statement is false, but  these are the lines I am thinking along to solve for $\alpha$. Looking forward to your inputs.

Comment: Please reformulate your question to make it clearer. What is given? You know $\mu$ or $\sigma^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to standardize.  If $X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then $X = \sigma Z + \mu$ where $Z \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1)$.  Then we have $$0.8 = \Pr[X \le 15] = \Pr[\sigma Z + \mu \le 15] = \Pr\left[Z \le \frac{15 - \mu}{\sigma} \right] = \Phi\left(\frac{15-\mu}{\sigma}\right), \tag{1}$$
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution.

Similarly,
$$\alpha = \Pr[X \le 10] = \Phi\left(\frac{10 - \mu}{\sigma}\right). \tag{2}$$
From $(1)$, we have $15 - \mu = \sigma \Phi^{-1}(0.8)$ or $10 - \mu = \sigma \Phi^{-1}(0.8) - 5$; hence $$\alpha = \Phi\left(\frac{\sigma \Phi^{-1}(0.8) - 5}{\sigma}\right) = \Phi\left(\Phi^{-1}(0.8) - \frac{5}{\sigma}\right). \tag{3}$$  Because $\Phi$ is a monotonically increasing function, $\alpha$ is minimized if $5/\sigma$ is made as large as possible.  Since $\sigma > 0$, we conclude that $\alpha \to 0$ as $\sigma \to 0^+$ and $\mu \to 15$.

For example, we can calculate the following table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\sigma & \mu = 15 - \sigma \Phi^{-1}(0.8) & \alpha = \Pr[X \le 10] \\
\hline
 3 & 12.4751 & 0.204673 \\
 2 & 13.3168 & 0.0486205 \\
 1 & 14.1584 & 0.0000160257 \\
 0.5 & 14.5792 & 2.63414 \times 10^{-20} \\
 0.1 & 14.9158 & 0. \\
 0.01 & 14.9916 & 0. \\
 0.001 & 14.9992 & 0. \\
\end{array}$$
For the last three rows of this table, the probability is so small that it is below the machine precision to calculate.  They are on the order of approximately $10^{-526}$, $10^{-54107}$, and $10^{-5426858}$.
This makes sense because the condition $\Pr[X \le 15] = 0.8$ does not restrict us from choosing $X$ to have as small a variance as we please while still having $80\%$ of the probability below $15$:  we just move the mean $\mu$ slightly below $15$, as shown in the table above.  But because the variance can be made arbitrarily small, the probability $\Pr[X \le 10]$ becomes vanishing.